# Adding metallic/glossy surface to dissolve effect

Tags: texturing, materials, shader-nodes

New to blender, and attempting a sort of material wipe, one material is wiped away revealing another one. I'm having trouble formatting this in a way to add a metallic/glossy texture to the black portion of the sword.

I do know how to use the principled bsdf in normal situations, but I've tried placing it in many different spots and none seem to work.

I've attached a screenshot of the shader setup, and 2 different frames of the animation to give an idea of what I'm doing. And if anyone wants to know, I'm working in evee.

Shader setup: https://gyazo.com/aca1da1aba143207557e243ee5b45e5c

Example frame 1: https://gyazo.com/96008081c517e50e94c0d94424c095f9

Example 2: https://gyazo.com/a5701659642a536c1bdca59c76d4634b

Comment: Please use the built-in screenshot adding system to add screenshots to stackexchange questions. In the meantime, you can probably do what you need with a gradient texture, and a Math node set to Greater Than, with the threshold animated.

Answer (score 3):

you can replicate this effect with this node setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

The "trick" is to use the mix shader node. The factor value decides which material it should take for each pixel.
To animate this we don't take a constant value, but we animate it.
In my example i took the y coordinate of the object and compared this to an animated value. Because a comparison with a constant value would just be a line distribution and a bit boring i also added some noise to make the effect a bit more interesting. You could of course add here different texture value e.g. wave, gradient...whatever you like. Shader nodes is damn powerful.

boring "line" example: (constant comparison)

[image]

wave example:

[image]

other wave example:

[image]

Comment: You really are having fun, here :D

Comment: Finally i understood 2% of the shader nodes and it’s just awesome. And yes…lot‘s of fun with BLENDER 